# Counting solutions to $a\cdot(b+c) = a\cdot b\cdot c$ in $[0,10]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the number of ways in which the following relation is true: $a\cdot(b+c)=a\cdot b\cdot c$.
Where $a,b,c$  belong to $[0,10]$.

Comment: I would first divide by $a$ (careful when $a=0)$. Also I suppose that your set is discrete and not really an interval.

Comment: Hey @dk welcome to Math.SE. I'll recommend you to read about using LaTeX in making your questions look better. You can read the manual of Math.SE.

Comment: In addition to @MayankM.'s comment , see this https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thanks @JaideepKhare it was useful to even me. Bookmarked it.

Comment: The word "permutation" in the title and the tag [tag:combinatorics] seem ill suited to this Question.  The problem seems more about high school algebra/precalculus topics ("Find the number of ways..." concerns solutions to an elementary equation).

Answer (score 2):

**Case I :**  $a=0$, the equation is satisfied $\forall~ b,c \in [0,10]$ .

**Case II :** $a \neq 0$ , Cancel out $a$. you will get :

$$b+c=b c \implies (b-1)(c-1)=1 $$

Now there are $2$ cases : $(b-1)=1,(c-1)=1 ~;~(b-1)=-1,(c-1)=-1$ 
$\implies (b,c)=(2,2) ; (0,0)$

Hence solutions are :

$$\boxed{(a,b,c)= (0,b,c) ; (a,0,0); (a,2,2) }$$
Where $a,b,c$ represent $ ~\forall ~a,b,c$.

Now, I leave counting solutions up to you.

Comment: Thanx and  Sorry as i am completely new here. I think i had got the same answer. But d solution in d book is different. So my guess is d books solution is wrong

Comment: @dk Why are you sorry?

Comment: Lol sorry because i am new here..so the title might have been misleading.

Answer (score -1):

I assume that all the numbers are integers.
For $a = 0$ the equality always holds, so we get $11^2 = 121$ different pairs of the following form: 
$$(0, b, c), \quad b,c \in [0, 10]$$

Suppose $a \neq 0$. Then we can divide both sides by $a$ and obtain an equivalent equation:
$$b + c = bc \Leftrightarrow bc - b - c + 1 = 1 \Rightarrow (b-1)(c-1) = 1$$

Here we shall note that $b-1$ and $c-1$ are integers, so either $b-1$ and $c-1$ are both equl to 1 or they both equal to -1. Both cases meet all the constraints, so, overall, we end up with $121 + 2 = 123$ possible solutions.

Comment: In d secnd case..when (b-1)(c-1)=1 shudnt it be 11*2 ways as a can take any integral value between 0 and 10?